# Show not matching strings in two files

Tags: awk, grep

I am trying to do a mutiple search. In one file I've got some words and I want to get back those which are not in the second one.

For example if I got *lamp* and *cat* in file 1 and *I love cats* in file 2, I need to have back *lamp*. File 1 would be a list of 2.800 words and file 2 a book with 900.000 words. I'm looking to get those of the 2.800 that do not appear.

Is it possible somehow?

I've tried this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i in a) delete a[$i]}} END {for (i in a) print i}' File1.rtf File2.rtf
```

and this

```
while read word; do grep -q "$word" File2.rtf || echo "$word"; done < File1.rtf
```

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: `cat` and `cats` are not the same word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your filenames suggest that you're dealing with RTF files, which you'd need to convert to plain text first.
- Your `awk`-based solution attempt would only work if (a) the 2nd file contained no punctuation and (b) it is acceptable to treat word variations (such as `cat` vs. `cats`) as separate words.
- Your `grep`-based solution will be very slow, because it creates a `grep` child process for every word in the list. Aside from that, it performs *substring* matching, which is probably not what you want.

The following variation of your `awk` command assumes plain-text input files and 
that variations of a word can be treated separately; in other words: it only addresses the punctuation problem:

```
$ awk '
  FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} 
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      # Remove punctuation from the field (word).
      gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "", $i)
      if ($i in a) delete a[$i]}
    } 
  END {for (i in a) print i}
' <(echo $'lamp\ncat') <(echo 'I love my cat.')
lamp
```

Also note that the output words will be in no particular order, because the ordering of keys of an Awk array is undefined (it is an implementation detail).

Overall, you should consider specialized tools that support [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming); also, sorting your word list and the words in the book beforehand may speed up things.